# Is it possible to conclude unstability if derivative of equilibrium point is zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm classifying the equilibrium points of the system $\dot{x}=f(x)=x(x-1)^2$. $x=1$ is one of them, and looking at the graphic of $\dot{x}$ versus $x$, I concluded is not stable. Nonetheless, I would like to conclude the same answer from it's derivative like in [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461907/) . In my case, $f'(1)=0$, so I can't conclude anything, how can I do it without plotting the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But $f''(1)\ne 0$, so locally $x=1+u$ behaves similar to $$\dot u=cu^2,$$ this gives semi-stable behavior.

You could also just argue by the signs in the intervals between and outside the roots.